# How to get a field value from one model to another model

Tags: python, odoo-8

I created a new module which depends on sales.  I also created a sales commission tab in sales order.  I would like to add `amount_total` from the `sale.order` to `sales_value` in my new model `commission.sale` but nothing happens.

In commission.py

```
_name = 'commission.sale'
sales_value = fields.Float(compute="_total", string="Sale Value")

@api.multi
    def _total(self):
        sale_obj = self.env['sale.order'].search([('amount_total','=', True)])
        self.sales_value = self.sale_obj.amount_total
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  `self.sale_obj` is not defined anywhere here.  Even if you drop the `self`,  you will probably find a lot of sale orders with that search so `sale_obj.amount_total` should give you an error.

Comment: no error and no output

Comment: Have you added your new field to a view xml file?

Comment: yes i created a tree view in `sale.order` including this field

Comment: your question isn't clear, the search request wil return no values because amount_total isn't boolean field  , and you didn't link your field with a specific  record !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class salesman_commission(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesman_commission'

    user = fields.Many2one('res.users',string='User')
    sales_order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order',string='Sale id',ondelete='cascade')
    sales_val = fields.Float(compute='_total',string='Sales Value')
    percent = fields.Float(string='Percent')
    commission = fields.Integer(compute='_commission',string='Commission')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('sales_order_id.amount_total')
    def _total(self):
        self.sales_val = self.sales_order_id.amount_total
```